# TableViewCell auto layout issue

Tags: ios, uitableview, constraints

I'm trying to set up constraints in my tableview cell, i'm using auto layout, iOS 11, Xcode 9. I have the same cell but plus two buttons in it and last cell is laying out perfectly. This cell is problematic. Here's screenshots:
[image]

and result:
[image]

update:[image: update]
result:[image: result update]

few more screenshots with "Name" and "Shortname" constraints:[image: Name]
[image: shortname]

Comment: did u set width and height of image?

Comment: Yes, its only makes image right dimensions, but labels are stll on image

Comment: Do you see any warning or error messages? It *looks* like your `Name.leading` constraints are conflicting...

Comment: No, 0 errors / warnings

Comment: I'd suggest deleting all constraints, and then adding them back one-by-one. Looking at your image, right now for example you appear to have `Avatar.top = topMargin` & `Avatar.bottom = bottomMargin` & `Avatar.centerY = centerY` ... no reason to have centerY ***and*** top & bottom.

Comment: try to link image to top and left (remove center y and bottom constraints)

Comment: even if i set width and height, leading, bottom & top, image is still in x: 0 & y: 0 position (i'm not setting labels constraints, only image for left, top, bottom and width/height)

Comment: only with top & left xcode asks me for height and width, and without these two image becomes on full cell length, with height and width its still x:0 and y:0

Comment: i don't know why but i cant normally upload images on stackoverflow but if i'm watching ui hierarchy and tap on my image view i see only height and width constraints activated, two others are just disabled, also image position is x:0, y:0

Comment: @Pselok - did you try deleting the constraints and starting fresh? If not... delete all constraints... set width and height constraints for Avatar... set Top, Left/Leading and Bottom for Avatar... run the app, see if Avatar is in the right place and is the right size. If so, add constraints for `Name` label... only top to top of Avatar and leading to trailing of Avatar (probably +8)... run the app, see if `Name` shows up where it should.

Comment: @DonMag i've tried, each time i'm trying from fresh start, everything is fine only without constraints

Comment: @Pselok - ok... so, you set width, height, top, left and bottom constraints on `Avatar` ... does it show up properly?

Comment: @DonMag yes, result the same as the last screenshot with result, `Avatar` is in same X: 0, Y: 0 position and has only two constraints on width and height activated, else constraints are just grey color and seems to be deactivated

Comment: OK - it doesn't do any good to set **only** the width and height on `Avatar` ... you must **also** set *at least* Top and Left. Try that, and see if the Avatar image view shows up correctly.

Comment: only with top & left xcode asks me for height and width, and without these two image becomes on full cell length, with height and width its still x:0 and y:0

Comment: *sigh* .... Set Width and Height constraints AND set Top and Left.

Comment: sorry, i know how it hurts, my head is hot as sun for those 2 days, but i've also tried width and height AND top and left :p

Comment: Are you doing anything in code? Setting frames or something? I set only width, height, top and left/leading and get this result: https://imgur.com/a/vZrqz

Comment: No i'm not doing anything in code, i only have search bar as header view but i've also tried without search bar, result is the same. I'm telling you, i have the same cell but only with two more buttons in addition and everything is perfect with second cell. But this cell is magic

Comment: Also, cell is fixed size of 64

Comment: Delete the cell, add a new one as a prototype, and add your elements one at a time. I don't know how it could happen, but I have seen people say (claim?) that their storyboard somehow was corrupted or holding some invalid reference in the cell prototype. Certainly worth a try.

Comment: Sure, thanks, i'll try it out

Comment: thanks, @DonMag, problem is solved, deleted the cell and added it again

Answer (score 0):

Based on your screenshot, there are some missing constraints needed in your `UIImageView`. Such as constant `height`, `leading to superView` and `top or bottom to superView`.

Comment: Yes i’ve already set height & width, also leading to superview and top and bottom. I’ve tried everything

Comment: updated, as i said it's only makes image view set normal dimensions as i set (48x48)

Answer (score 0):

Delete the cell and add again solved the issue